# Codeception and Selenium: Can't set cookie

Tags: php, selenium, cookies, codeception

For one of my Selenium Cests I want to set a cookie but this is simply not working. In order to find the problem I reduced my code to the absolut minimum and to my surprise setting cookies seems not to work at all.

```
 /**
 * Test if we can set simple cookies
 *
 * @param \AcceptanceTester $i
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function settingCookieSetsCookie(AcceptanceTester $i)
{
    $cookieDefaultParams = [
        'path' => '/',
        'secure' => false,
        'httpOnly' => false,
        'expiry' => 900,
        'domain' => 'www.testdomain.local'
    ];

    $i->amOnPage('/cookieCest.php');
    $i->setCookie('example', 'myvalue', $cookieDefaultParams);
    $i->amOnPage('/cookieCest.php'); // reload page
    $cookieValue = $i->grabCookie('example');
    $i->assertEquals('myvalue', $cookieValue);
}
```

For testing purposes I set up a local test domain www.testdomain.local which works fine.

Unfortunately the above test fails with the following error:

> There was 1 failure:
>
> ---
>
> 1) BackendLoginCest: Setting cookie sets cookie  Test  codeception\acceptance\CookieCest.php:settingCookieSetsCookie  Step 
>   Assert equals "myvalue",null  Fail  Failed asserting that null matches
>   expected 'myvalue'.
>
> Scenario Steps:
>
> 5. $I->assertEquals("myvalue",null) at codeception\acceptance\CookieCest.php:36
> 6. $I->grabCookie("example") at codeception\acceptance\CookieCest.php:35
> 7. $I->amOnPage("/cookieCest.php") at codeception\acceptance\CookieCest.php:34
> 8. $I->setCookie("example","myvalue",{"path":"/","secure":false,"httpOnly":false,"expiry":900,"domain":"www.new-ep...})
>      at codeception\acceptance\CookieCest.php:33
> 9. $I->amOnPage("/cookieCest.php") at codeception\acceptance\CookieCest.php:32
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.`

As far as I can see the cookie params configuration looks good (and seems to be needed, as leaving it out results in an error).

I am currently using selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar but tried older versions which produce the same problem.

The referenced file `cookieCest.php` is just a simple script which var_dumps `$_COOKIE` so I can see that there are no cookie values available in PHP.

Does anyone experience a similar problem and knows how to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. What may be a solution is that the page is not loaded when you want to set the cookie so it fails there.

Also if you want to check your cookie you can use the function `seeCookie` like:

Try this solution and let me know if it did any change.

```
$i->amOnPage('/cookieCest.php');
$i->wait(5); 
$i->setCookie('example', 'myvalue', $cookieDefaultParams);
$i->seeCookie('example');
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding a delay does not solve the problerm. Cookie still won't be set :-(

Comment: What does the `seeCookie` return? If the cookie is not set this step should fail

Comment: In my case, running `amOnPage` (also) before `setCookie` helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this test with older Chrome version (e.g. 66).
I think all cookie related stuff are broken with last several Chrome versions.